# how can I configure swashbuckle to display the api version instead of the v{version} variable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to document my Web API 2.2 API. When I load the Swagger page, the uri's display with a version placeholder variable instead of the actual version.  For example:

```
/api/v{version}/authentication
```

Instead of:

```
/api/v2/authentication
```

How can I configure my app or Swashbuckle to display the version number instead of the version variable?

Comment: Will be hard to provide an accurate answer with just these few details...
@Sanmoy Can you provide a sample project reproducing your issue

Answer (score 2):

Updated code for WebApiConfig:

```
// Web API configuration and services
            var constraintResolver = new System.Web.Http.Routing.DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
            {
                ConstraintMap =
                {
                    ["apiVersion"] = typeof(Microsoft.Web.Http.Routing.ApiVersionRouteConstraint)
                }
            };

            config.AddVersionedApiExplorer(opt =>
            {
                opt.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;

            });

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
            config.AddApiVersioning();

            // Web API routes
            //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Some references [Swagger](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-URL-Path)

Comment: I'm not using asp.net core

Comment: Good to know! Would've been much easier if you indicated that code so people will have an idea on what you were using. Anyway, I've updated my code to the correct type of ASP.Net you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just noticed you are talking about the URI ...not sure if below will help

Have you tried something like below in your swagger config :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config
        .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "version api");                
            c.PrettyPrint();
            c.OAuth2("oauth2").Description("OAuth2 ResourceOwner Grant").TokenUrl("/testtoken");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
            c.DocumentFilter<AuthTokenOperation>();
            c.DocumentFilter<ListManagementSwagger>();
            c.SchemaFilter<SchemaExamples>();
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentTitle("test webapi");                
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways to implement versioning. I have a custom header and custom root url function, you can ignore that part.  This code is asking Swagger to build two different versions from the xml provided.

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {

        var customHeader = new SwaggerHeader  //you can ignore this one
        {
            Description = "Custom header description",
            Key = "customHeaderId",
            Name = "customHeaderId"
        };

        var versionSupportResolver = new Func<ApiDescription, string, bool>((apiDescription, version) =>
        {
            var path = apiDescription.RelativePath.Split('/');
            var pathVersion = path[1];
            return string.Equals(pathVersion, version, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        });

        var versionInfoBuilder = new Action<VersionInfoBuilder>(info => {
            info.Version("v2", "My API v2");
            info.Version("v1", "My API v1");
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                //c.RootUrl(ComputeHostAsSeenByOriginalClient);  //you can ignore this custom function
                c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });
                customHeader.Apply(c);
                c.MultipleApiVersions(versionSupportResolver, versionInfoBuilder);
                c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
                c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi("swagger/ui/{*assetPath}", c =>
            {
                c.DisableValidator();
                c.SupportedSubmitMethods("GET", "POST");
            });
    }

    private static Func<XPathDocument> GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return () =>
        {
            var xapixml = GetXDocument("My.API.xml");
            var xElement = xapixml.Element("doc");
            XPathDocument xPath = null;
            if (xElement != null)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var xws = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = false };
                    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, xws))
                    {
                        xElement.WriteTo(xw);
                    }
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    xPath = new XPathDocument(ms);
                }
            }
            return xPath;
        };
    }

    private static XDocument GetXDocument(string file)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\" + file);
        return xDoc;
    }

    //ComputeHostAsSeenByOriginalClient function code

}
```